Ben Hur set reference in Good Omens?
In season 2 episode 2 of the "Good Omens" TV series, a scene occurs about halfway through with Aziraphale and Crowley. The space looks to me a lot like Ben Hur's home as it appeared in the 1959 Charlton Heston movie - with the placement of doors, the stairway, and other features. Is this co-incidence or was this set actually either inspired by the 1959 movie, or an intentional reference to it?

Yes. According to the show's concept artist, Jim McCarthy it was intended to be an homage.

Good Omens 2 Job's courtyard.
This was a little homage to Ben Hur, the 1959 film.

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/n0KPJX

